# For which type of parallel algorithms is Hadoop well suited?

Tags: algorithm, hadoop, parallel-processing

I'm no expert at all of Hadoop, but is my understanding that Hadoop is well suited for parallel algorithms where the parallelism lies either as a map-reduce form or any other kind of divide and conquer.

Are there other class of algorithm techniques that are well suited as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop is suited for embarrassingly parallel workload (no dependency between parallel tasks). There is no mechanism of message passing between processes. Map and Reduce processes follow an IO based communication pattern, which itself is a great overhead.

Map Reduce is not suitable for programming iterative algorithms (for example KMeans, PageRank) because each iteration is a separate map reduce application and due to huge IO overhead the performance of your algorithm degrades. For iterative algorithms you can use Message Passing Interfaces (MPI). It supports socket based communication between processes, hence you can achieve significant improvement in performance as compared to map reduce. Since a large number of machine learning algorithms are iterative in nature, mapreduce should not be used for programming them.

If fault tolerance is necessary for your application, Hadoop is a better option than MPI.